# Cannot uninstall Gradle on Ubuntu WSL

Tags: apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gradle

I installed Gradle at one time to do some Java, and I have since installed it on Windows and no longer need it on my WSL system.

When I write `gradle -v` everything seems to be fine.

However, when I attempt to uninstall, I get the message below. Grepping `apt list` on gradle shows all packages are present.

What can I do to fix this and remove gradle ?

```bsh
gordon@eng:/$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-02-22 16:13:28 UTC
Revision:     9e26b4a9ebb910eaa1b8da8ff8575e514bc61c78

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.10 (Ubuntu 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OS:           Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard amd64
```

```
gordon@eng:/$ sudo apt remove gradle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gradle' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
```

Comment: What is the output of `type gradle`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. The output is :

gradle is hashed (/mnt/c/Gradle/gradle-6.8.3/bin/gradle)

It's actually under /mnt/c which is my windows partition, does that mean wsl is accessing the same program as the windows install by some compatibility magic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu (WSL) in your system is using Gradle available in Windows. From [Share environment variables between Windows and WSL - Windows interoperability with Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#share-environment-variables-between-windows-and-wsl)
:

> WSL and Windows share a special environment variable, `WSLENV`, created to bridge Windows and Linux distributions running on WSL.

If you run `echo $PATH`, you'll see Windows folders added. So, essentially, Gradle *isn't* installed in Ubuntu.

If you want to disable interoperability, you can run:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop
```

Now, you won't be able to use Windows programs in WSL, for example, File Explorer, although, you may still see Windows folders in `PATH`.

To re-enable interoperability, run:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop
```

Comment: This clears things up, thank you so much !

Comment: I like it - Usually I just recommend that people with these sorts of problems look at creating a `/etc/wsl.conf`, but your solution is certainly better for the one-time need that this question had.

Comment: Also a quick note - You seem to have quoted the wrong line from that page.  You quoted from the *"Share environment variables between Windows and WSL"* section.  `WSLENV` doesn't have much to do with running Windows commands in WSL, nor the path.  It's just used for making Windows' environment variables (other than the PATH) available to WSL.